# onClick edit the Future CSS within a Textbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a basic document processing suite in React.  I have a bold button created, but I can't figure out how to edit the CSS of the text in the textbox.  I am sure this is possible I'm just unsure how to make it happen.  I think my syntax is wrong, among other things.  Any help would be great

```
export default function Bold() {

    boldStyle = { fontWeight: 'bold'}
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="bold" onClick={boldStyle}>B</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an HOC that takes in children?